# Unique values from one column using ActiveAndroid?

Tags: activeandroid

I'm trying to get all unique values from a single column from a table.  I'm utterly failing, and the docs don't seem to go into enough depth, and what I've gleaned from looking at the source seems like that should help, but doesn't.

```
List<Question> questions = new Select().from(Question.class).where("ZCLASSLEVEL = ? ", classLevel).execute();
```

works to get *all* the columns of *all* the Questions.

However,

```
List<Question> questions = new Select(columns).from(Question.class).where("ZCLASSLEVEL = ? ", classLevel).execute();
```

doesn't return any data (questions.size() = 0), where I've tried

```
String[] columns = { "ZHRSSECTION" };
```

and

```
Select.Column[] columns = { new Select.Column("ZHRSSECTION", "ZHRSSECTION")};
```

Presumably, throwing `.distinct().` after the Select() should return only unique values, but I can't even get just the single column I'm interested in to get returned.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!
randy

Answer (score 1):

You should use **`groupBy()`** method to make the use of **`distinct()`** method.

For example:

```
List<Question> questions = new Select()
    .distinct()
    .from(Question.class)
    .groupBy("ZCLASSLEVEL")
    .execute();
```

The above code returns a list of Questions, one for each ZCLASSLEVEL (probably the last row).

Then you can get the **unique** values of ZCLASSLEVEL as

```
for(Question question: questions){
    int level = question.ZCLASSLEVEL;
    //do something with level.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late in answering this, but the issue is because SQLiteUtils.rawQuery() makes the assumption that the Id column is always going to be in the cursor result.   Set your columns String[] to {Id, ZHRSSECTION} and you'll be fine.

```
    List<FooRecord> list = new Select(new String[]{"Id,tagName"}).from(FooRecord.class).execute();
```

Comment: thanks but this does not return unique value of that column :( .